# How to delete a row from GridView and set the remaining values to the controls?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

Ok,[CLICK ME !](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Adding-Dynamic-Rows-in-ASP.Net-GridView-Control-with-TextBoxes.aspx)
THis is what i have right now... but i want to add a delete functionality. I have added a delete command button column and on its click event i am deleting the particular row.
But my problem is that i am unable to retain the remaining row's values in the controls.

```
protected void Gridview1_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
    {
        DataTable dtCurrentTable=new DataTable();
        int RowIndex = e.RowIndex;
        dtCurrentTable = (DataTable)ViewState["CurrentTable"];
        dtCurrentTable.Rows.RemoveAt(e.RowIndex);

        SetPreviousData1(dtCurrentTable);

    }

private void SetPreviousData1(DataTable dtCurrentTable)
    {
        int rowIndex = 0;
        if (dtCurrentTable != null)
        {
            DataTable dt = dtCurrentTable;
            if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    TextBox box1 = (TextBox)Gridview1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[1].FindControl("TextBox1");
                    TextBox box2 = (TextBox)Gridview1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[2].FindControl("TextBox2");
                    TextBox box3 = (TextBox)Gridview1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[3].FindControl("TextBox3");

                    box1.Text = dt.Rows[i]["Column1"].ToString();
                    box2.Text = dt.Rows[i]["Column2"].ToString();
                    box3.Text = dt.Rows[i]["Column3"].ToString();

                    rowIndex++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Please note i am not fetching anything from database.

**UPDATE(rest of my code)**

```
private void SetInitialRow()
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        DataRow dr = null;
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("RowNumber", typeof(string)));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Column1", typeof(string)));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Column2", typeof(string)));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Column3", typeof(string)));
        dr = dt.NewRow();
        dr["RowNumber"] = 1;
        dr["Column1"] = string.Empty;
        dr["Column2"] = string.Empty;
        dr["Column3"] = string.Empty;
        dt.Rows.Add(dr);

        //Store the DataTable in ViewState
        ViewState["CurrentTable"] = dt;

        Gridview1.DataSource = dt;
        Gridview1.DataBind();
    }
    private void AddNewRowToGrid()
    {
        int rowIndex = 0;

        if (ViewState["CurrentTable"] != null)
        {
            DataTable dtCurrentTable = (DataTable)ViewState["CurrentTable"];
            DataRow drCurrentRow = null;
            if (dtCurrentTable.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                for (int i = 1; i <= dtCurrentTable.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    //extract the TextBox values
                    TextBox box1 = (TextBox)Gridview1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[1].FindControl("TextBox1");
                    TextBox box2 = (TextBox)Gridview1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[2].FindControl("TextBox2");
                    TextBox box3 = (TextBox)Gridview1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[3].FindControl("TextBox3");

                    drCurrentRow = dtCurrentTable.NewRow();
                    drCurrentRow["RowNumber"] = i + 1;

                    dtCurrentTable.Rows[i - 1]["Column1"] = box1.Text;
                    dtCurrentTable.Rows[i - 1]["Column2"] = box2.Text;
                    dtCurrentTable.Rows[i - 1]["Column3"] = box3.Text;

                    rowIndex++;
                }
                dtCurrentTable.Rows.Add(drCurrentRow);
                ViewState["CurrentTable"] = dtCurrentTable;

                Gridview1.DataSource = dtCurrentTable;
                Gridview1.DataBind();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Response.Write("ViewState is null");
        }

        //Set Previous Data on Postbacks
        SetPreviousData();
    }
    private void SetPreviousData()
    {
        int rowIndex = 0;
        if (ViewState["CurrentTable"] != null)
        {
            DataTable dt = (DataTable)ViewState["CurrentTable"];
            if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    TextBox box1 = (TextBox)Gridview1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[1].FindControl("TextBox1");
                    TextBox box2 = (TextBox)Gridview1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[2].FindControl("TextBox2");
                    TextBox box3 = (TextBox)Gridview1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[3].FindControl("TextBox3");

                    box1.Text = dt.Rows[i]["Column1"].ToString();
                    box2.Text = dt.Rows[i]["Column2"].ToString();
                    box3.Text = dt.Rows[i]["Column3"].ToString();

                    rowIndex++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            SetInitialRow();
        }
    }
    protected void ButtonAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        AddNewRowToGrid();
    }
```

**ASPX**

```
<asp:gridview ID="Gridview1" runat="server" ShowFooter="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" OnRowDeleting="Gridview1_RowDeleting">
            <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="RowNumber" HeaderText="Row Number" />
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Header 1">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Header 2">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Header 3">
                <ItemTemplate>
                     <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <FooterStyle HorizontalAlign="Right" />
                <FooterTemplate>
                 <asp:Button ID="ButtonAdd" runat="server" Text="Add New Row" 
                        onclick="ButtonAdd_Click" />
                </FooterTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:CommandField DeleteText="D" HeaderText="D" ShowDeleteButton="true" />
            </Columns>
        </asp:gridview>
```

Comment: @SamieyMehdi what do you mean?? Its right at the top in my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update you gridview to following:

```
<asp:gridview ID="Gridview1" runat="server" ShowFooter="true" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
                <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="RowNumber" HeaderText="Row Number" />
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Header 1">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Header 2">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>

                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Header 3">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                         <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <FooterStyle HorizontalAlign="Right" />
                    <FooterTemplate>
                     <asp:Button ID="ButtonAdd" runat="server" Text="Add New Row" 
                            onclick="ButtonAdd_Click" />
                    </FooterTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                  <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Header 2">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="lnkDel" OnCommand="DeleteRowHandler" Text="delete"></asp:LinkButton>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                </Columns>
            </asp:gridview>
```

Now add following code to you .cs page.

```
  protected void DeleteRowHandler(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
    {
        GridViewRow row = ((GridViewRow) ((LinkButton)sender).Parent.Parent);
        DataTable dt = = new DataTable();
    DataRow dr = null;
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("RowNumber", typeof(string)));
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Column1", typeof(string)));
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Column2", typeof(string)));
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Column3", typeof(string)));
    for (int i = 0; i < Gridview1.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        dr = dt.NewRow();
        dr[1] = ((TextBox)Gridview1.Rows[i].Cells[1].FindControl("TextBox1")).Text;
        dr[2] = ((TextBox)Gridview1.Rows[i].Cells[2].FindControl("TextBox1")).Text;
        dr[3] = ((TextBox)Gridview1.Rows[i].Cells[3].FindControl("TextBox1")).Text;
        dt.Rows.Add(dr);
    }
        dt.Rows.RemoveAt(row.RowIndex);
        ViewState["CurrentTable"] = dt;
        Gridview1.DataSource = dt;
        Gridview1.DataBind();
    }
```

Comment: `A field or property with the name 'RowNumber' was not found on the selected data source.`

Comment: It is working for me.I have updated your code. Download the updated code from here. http://pastelink.me/dl/71c8bc

Comment: I downloaded your code and its still not retaining the values in the textboxes when i delete any row.

Comment: Sorry, my friend for responding late. You were really very helpful. Thanks a lot. Jazak Allah Khair :)

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the rebinding of the data to the gridview after deleting the row.

Inside the `SetPreviousData1` function, add:

```
GridView1.DataSource=dtCurrentTable;
GridView1.DataBind();
```

Comment: I tried that , i wish it was that simple .. but its not working.. all rows get cleared when i delete a row.

Comment: Please update the question with the rest of your code, particularly the Page_Load